# Multivariable limit $\lim_{{x, y \to 0}}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please help me with this? I'm totally stuck on this! Tried polar coordinates but that doesn't bring anything. Does someone has any suggestion?

Find $\lim_{{x, y \to 0}}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=1$

Comment: "Find"...or "prove"?

Comment: sorry Prove "Printing Errors" :)

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=\lim_{r\to0} r^{2r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}=1$$

since it is similar to

$$\lim_{x\to0}x^{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{x^4\log x}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Now i get it. I tried polar coordinates but couldn't see similiarity which you refered. Thank you Joanpemo sincerely :)