# Limit with 2 variables: $\frac{x^2y}{x^4 +y^2}$, $\frac{e^{xy^3}-1}{x^2 +y^4}$ and $(x^2 +y^2)^{xy}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am new to this topic so I appreciate any help on this.

a)$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^4 +y^2}$$

For $x=0 \lor y=0 :  f(x,y) \longrightarrow 0$ but for $y = x^2$ the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ so the limit does not exist.

b)
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{e^{xy^3}-1}{x^2 +y^4}$$
I don't have any ideas here

c)
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y) = (x^2 +y^2)^{xy}$$
Let $x \geq y$ then $|x^2 +y^2|^{xy} \leq |2y^2|^{y^2} \longrightarrow 1 \quad $for $y \longrightarrow 0$ but for $x = \frac{1}{y} \Longrightarrow f(x,y) = (\frac{1}{y^2} + y^2)^1 \longrightarrow \infty \quad$ for $y \longrightarrow 0 $ so the limit does not exist.

Comment: For b): see what happens for $x = y^2$ and $x=-y^2$.

Comment: I get for both the limit $0$

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Comment: The first limit seems to be posted here rather frequently:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933949/multivariable-limit-frac2x2yx4y2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476353/help-with-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx2yx4y2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93886/computing-a-multivariable-limit
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174190/prove-that-lim-limits-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2-y4-0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780919/showing-a-function-is-discontinuous-by-taking-a-limit
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837256

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2Cy)%20%5Crightarrow%20(0%2C0)%7D%20(x%5E2%20%2By%5E2)%5E%7Bxy%7D%24&p=1) I found this question about the limit c: [Multivariable limit $\lim_{{x, y \to 0}}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1733965)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For b):

we have that $f(0,y) = f(x, 0) = 0$ for every $x,y\neq 0$.
If $x$ and $y$ are both non zero, we have that
$$
\frac{e^{xy^3} - 1}{x^2+y^4} = \frac{e^{xy^3} - 1}{xy^3}\cdot \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}.
$$
The first factor at the r.h.s. is bounded (for $x,y$ bounded), since $(e^t-1)/t \to 1$ as $t\to 0$.

The second factor can be estimated by
$$
\left|\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}\right| =
|y| \cdot \frac{|x| y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{|y|}{2}.
$$

Hence the limit exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: I see, i could have used a) for this. Thats very helpful

Comment: what makes the second factor bounded by y/2? we cannot say the max of second factor is 1/2 through part a

Comment: $|ab| / (a^2+b^2) \leq 1/2$ for every $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to process is to set $y=mx^\alpha$ with some well chosen $\alpha>0$ so that the various sums $x^a+y^b$ become homogeneous.

Of course $m=m(x,y)$ is not a constant, just the ratio of the rate of convergence of $x$ and $y$.

#### Part a:

With $y=mx^2$

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{mx^4}{x^4+m^2x^4}=\frac{m}{1+m^2}$

This is bounded but can take multiple values (e.g $m=1,\ f(x,x^2)=\frac 12$ and $m=0,\ f(x,0)=0$), so there is no limit in $(0,0)$.

#### Part b:

With $x=my^2$

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{e^{x^3y}-1}{x^2+y^4}\sim\frac {x^3y}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{m^3y^7}{m^2y^4+y^4}=\frac{m^3y^3}{1+m^2}=\underbrace{\bigg(\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}\bigg)}_\text{bounded}xy\to 0$

So there is a limit and it is $0$.

#### Part c:

The previous method do not work well here, but polar coordinates do

$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{xy}=\exp(xy\ln(x^2+y^2))=\exp(\underbrace{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}_\text{bounded}\underbrace{r^2\ln(r^2)}_{\to 0})\to e^0=1$

Comment: Be careful. Looking along families of curves will only prove a limit does *not* exist, not that it does.

Comment: Please read, **m is not a constant**, no matter how many time I write this, people don't see it. These are not curves.

Comment: It's still very misleading. How do you handle $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & |y|>|x|^3 \text{ or } y=0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ or $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & |y|>e^{-1/x^2} \text{ or } y=0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$?

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in c): $(1/y,y)$ does not approach $(0,0)$ as $y\to 0.$

To do it, we can apply $\ln$ to get $xy\ln (x^2+y^2).$ Recall $|xy|\le (x^2+y^2)/2.$ Thus

$$\tag 1 |xy \ln (x^2+y^2)| \le \frac{(x^2+y^2)\ln (x^2+y^2)}{2}.$$

Now $u\ln u \to 0$ as $u\to 0^+.$ Thus the limit of $(1)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ is $0.$ This implies the orginal limit is $1.$